# Adding markers to histogram with fitted distribution curve in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, curve-fitting

Hello so I created a function that creates a histogram with a fitted curve using histfit given a specified number of bins, but I also need to add separate markers at the center of each bar in the histogram that follow the fitted curve. How would I go about this? I considered using the XData and YData from the curve then replotting with a different line, but I could not figure out how to get it to actually plot at the center of each bar?

Comment: please add the code that you wrote so we can understand better

Comment: so did my answer helped you??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output argument during the call to `histfit` to obtain a handle to the graph produced, which contains all the infos for the patch object forming the histogram and the line object for the fit. Then it's just a matter of some math to get the midpoints in both the x- and y directions.

Here is an example:

```
clear
clc
close all

%// Generate data
rng default; 
r = normrnd(10,1,100,1);

%// Use output to get handle
hHist = histfit(r);

hold on
```

Now the patch data correspond to the 1st entry of `hHist`:

```
hHist = 

  2x1 graphics array:

  Patch
  Line
```

Get y data and find midpoints:

```
AllYData = get(hHist(1),'YData');

YData = AllYData(2,:)/2;
```

Note that `AllYData` is a 4x10 array containing the y coordinates of the 4 corners forming each individual bar. Hence we only need the maximal value (either of the 2 top corners).

Same thing for x data:

```
AllXData = get(hHist(1),'XData');
```

Here `AllXData` is a 4 x 10 array, containing the x coordinates of every corner of the bars forming the histogram. Hence we are only interested in the middle 2, forming the actual x range of each bar. Then figuring out the center is easy:

```
XRanges = AllXData(2:3,:);

MidPoints = sum(XRanges)/2;
```

And displaying everything with `scatter`: (you can use `plot` as well of course):

```
scatter(MidPoints,YData,80,'y','filled')
```

Output:

[image]

yay!